# VBA Getting double value from several worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet and I want a macro that search in the Excel sheet for double values.
I have several worksheets and the macro should search from 
Column A - First Value -> to Worksheet 2 Column A - First Value.

I have tried it with VBA, but it didnt work. Maybe some of you can help me!

```
Sub DoppelteEinträge()
   Dim Tabellen()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim n As Integer
   Dim z As Integer
   Dim AnzahlZellen As Integer
   Dim AnzahlTabellen As Integer
   Dim anzahldoppelte As Integer



AnzahlZellen = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
AnzahlTabellen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For i = 0 To 3
    ReDim Preserve Tabellen(i)
    Tabellen(i) = Worksheets(i + 1).Name
Next

For z = 1 To AnzahlTabellen

    For n = 1 To AnzahlZellen
        Worksheets(Tabellen(0)).Select
        Range("A" & n).Select

        If Range("A" & n) = Worksheets(Tabellen(z)).Range("A" & n) Then
        anzahldoppelte = anzahldoppelte + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: also, the count("A:A") is prone to error if you are assigning the value to Integer, use long instead, you will get overflow if you got many rows. i.e. more than 32k

Comment: also, add error catching and display the error message in a msgbox.

Comment: haha sorry im new to vba programming. Yes im getting an Error. Runtime Error 9

Comment: I think the default starting index for arrays in VBA is 1, does changing 0 to 1 in `Worksheets(Tabellen(0)).Select` fix anything? Do you even want a fixed number in that line?

Comment: also in your statement  If Range("A" & n) = Worksheets(Tabellen(z)).Range("A" & n) you use Range("A"&n), if you dont specify which sheet that Range("A"&n) refers to, it will refer the active sheet which might not be the one you want.

Comment: I tried to Change something but im getting Errors.

Comment: What did you change? What errors did you get and where?

Comment: Runtime Error 9 - I changed Worksheets(Tabellen(z) and this to Worksheets(Tabellen(y).Range but didnt work. I saw that the Loop is going trough the cells but it didnt check for double values.The error is coming at the end of the loop